# get a part of string just like accessing an array?

Tags: shell

In shell,

```
s="abc\tdef\tghi"   # 3 words separated by \t
```

What if I want to get the second word which is `def`?

PS

I know `cut` can do the job, but any way else just like variable substitution?

Comment: Do you mean a tab character or the 2 characters `\` and `t`? With that variable assignment, you'll get the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `cut` ?

```
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo -e $s | cut -f2
def
```

Or maybe `awk`:

```
echo -e $s | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Upvoted, `cut` is good, I just wanted to know any way else? Just like variable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this.

```
s="abc\tdef\tghi"
s=${s#*\t}
s=${s%\\t*}
echo $s
```